# Add navigationBar in existing project

Tags: iphone, integration, uinavigationbar

i have three viewController v1 v2 v3, to go from v1 to v2 i use pushViewController property of navigation controller, but from v2 to v3 i use presentviewController . in v3 i need navigation bar with button on right side so that i can perform method.
plesae help .

Comment: Create a custom navigation bar then.

Comment: without custom process, its not possible,

Comment: Then do custom process in v3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view controller V2, use below code to present your V3

```
V3 *obj_V3=[[V3 alloc]initWithNibName:@"V3" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:obj_V3];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navBar animated:YES];
[navBar release];
[obj_V3 release];
```

and in your V3 add

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(performMethod)] autorelease];
```

and your perform method

```
-(void)performMethod {
//your code
}
```

Comment: thank you crimeMaster Gogogo, you have taken my Code crime and provide solution its amazing